# How to access a specific key in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

```
 itemdetails = {101: { 'Item Name':'Tshirt', 'Price':150.00, 'Stock':20},
                102: { 'Item Name':'Shirt', 'Price':300.00, 'Stock':20},
                103: { 'Item Name':'Shorts', 'Price':450.00, 'Stock':20},
                104: { 'Item Name':'Trousers', 'Price':750.00, 'Stock':20}}


 option = str(input("Press [C] for Item Code , [N] for Item Name: "))
 if option=='n':
         itemname=(input("Enter Item name: "))
         print(itemdetails[itemname]) #====> how to access ???
 else:
         itemcode=int(input("Enter Item code: "))

         print(itemdetails[itemcode])
```

#When I enter itemname, I want it to list the whole subdictionary for that particular item name, for example if I enter Tshirt, I want to output  =====>
101: { 'Item Name':'Tshirt', 'Price':150.00, 'Stock':20}

is that possible?

Comment: First of all repair the formatting, please.

Comment: Can you clear the code a bit, or provide an desired input and output?

Comment: It sounds like you need a dict whose keys are the item names.  Otherwise you'll have to search all the entries to find it.

Comment: You can iterate through the `items()` of your dict, check the value (which is also a dict) to have the right value for key "Item Name" and show key and value of "itemdetails" in a formatted way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
itemdetails = {101: { 'Item Name':'Tshirt', 'Price':150.00, 'Stock':20},
                102: { 'Item Name':'Shirt', 'Price':300.00, 'Stock':20},
                103: { 'Item Name':'Shorts', 'Price':450.00, 'Stock':20},
                104: { 'Item Name':'Trousers', 'Price':750.00, 'Stock':20}}


 option = str(input("Press [C] for Item Code , [N] for Item Name: "))
 if option=='n':
         itemname=(input("Enter Item name: "))
         print(list(filter(lambda item: item['Item Name'] == itemname, itemdetails))[0])
 else:
         itemcode=int(input("Enter Item code: "))

         print(itemdetails[itemcode])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
item = 'Tshirt'
print([{k:v} for k,v in itemdetails.items() if v['Item Name'] == item][0])
```

Output

```
{101: {'Item Name': 'Tshirt', 'Price': 150.0, 'Stock': 20}}
```

-- To print the price with 2 decimal places, you will need to extract the value from the dictionary and print it.

```
item = 'Tshirt'
x =[{k:v} for k,v in itemdetails.items() if v['Item Name'] == item][0]
print(x)
price = [v for v in x.values()][0]['Price']
print('Price: {:.2f}'.format(price))
```

Output

```
{101: {'Item Name': 'Tshirt', 'Price': 150.0, 'Stock': 20}}
Price: 150.00
```

Comment: there is no need, in my opinion, to make list-comprehension and choose the first, you can directly use dict-comprehension as I exampled in my answer

Comment: This works fine thank you very much, Just wanna know how to print the 'Price' Value with 2 digits when displaying the dictionary. It returns 'Price':150.0

Answer (score 0):

If the information has to be accessed via itemname as keys only then probably you can consider changing the dict structure and directly hsing itemname as outer key.
However if it cannot be done, then you can create a separate dict that stores the id list number for every itemname. And then just pick the id for the itemname and get the required info from the original list. Otherwise you will have to go through all the keys in main dictionary, check if any one has the itemname as key in it and then return its content.

Answer (score 0):

I think that dict comprehension will do the work here, like so:

```
itemdetails = {101: { 'Item Name':'Tshirt', 'Price':150.00, 'Stock':20},
                102: { 'Item Name':'Shirt', 'Price':300.00, 'Stock':20},
                103: { 'Item Name':'Shorts', 'Price':450.00, 'Stock':20},
                104: { 'Item Name':'Trousers', 'Price':750.00, 'Stock':20}}
in_val = 'Shorts'       
out = {key:val for key,val in itemdetails.items() if val['Item Name']==in_val}

print(out)
```

output:

```
{103: {'Item Name': 'Shorts', 'Price': 450.0, 'Stock': 20}}
```

which `in_val` is the value of the item `Name field`, change it to whatever you want to.

not sure about the vertically format you wish to print in, but this format would probably do the work I hope:

**first version - mor 'fancy' one:**

```
print('\n'.join([str(list(a.keys())[0])] + [str(item) for item in a[103].items()]))
```

output:

```
103
('Item Name', 'Shorts')
('Price', 450.0)
('Stock', 20)
```

**second version - more readable one (and easier to fine tuning as you wish):**

```
for outer_key,outer_vals in a.items():
    print(f'outer key: {outer_key}')
    for inner_key,inner_val in outer_vals.items():
        print(f'inner_key: {inner_key}, inner_val: {inner_val}')
```

output:

```
outer key: 103
inner_key: Item Name, inner_val: Shorts
inner_key: Price, inner_val: 450.0
inner_key: Stock, inner_val: 20
```

Comment: Works fine Thank you. Is there a way I can print the output vertically?

Comment: Yes you can. not sure about your formatting - but take a look at my implementation. Enjoy my friend